# How to convert binary file to string in SuiteScript

Tags: suitescript

I'm loading file with nlapiLoadFile. It's binary file so when I'm getting the data with getValue() I see it's base64 encoded. How can I convert the data to string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently I'm using this, and it's working like a charm:

```
var Base64 = {
_keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=", encode: function (e) {
    var t = "";
    var n, r, i, s, o, u, a;
    var f = 0;
    e = Base64._utf8_encode(e);
    while (f < e.length) {
        n = e.charCodeAt(f++);
        r = e.charCodeAt(f++);
        i = e.charCodeAt(f++);
        s = n >> 2;
        o = (n & 3) << 4 | r >> 4;
        u = (r & 15) << 2 | i >> 6;
        a = i & 63;
        if (isNaN(r)) {
            u = a = 64
        } else if (isNaN(i)) {
            a = 64
        }
        t = t + this._keyStr.charAt(s) + this._keyStr.charAt(o) + this._keyStr.charAt(u) + this._keyStr.charAt(a)
    }
    return t
}, decode: function (e) {
    var t = "";
    var n, r, i;
    var s, o, u, a;
    var f = 0;
    e = e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]/g, "");
    while (f < e.length) {
        s = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
        o = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
        u = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
        a = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
        n = s << 2 | o >> 4;
        r = (o & 15) << 4 | u >> 2;
        i = (u & 3) << 6 | a;
        t = t + String.fromCharCode(n);
        if (u != 64) {
            t = t + String.fromCharCode(r)
        }
        if (a != 64) {
            t = t + String.fromCharCode(i)
        }
    }
    t = Base64._utf8_decode(t);
    return t
}, _utf8_encode: function (e) {
    e = e.replace(/rn/g, "n");
    var t = "";
    for (var n = 0; n < e.length; n++) {
        var r = e.charCodeAt(n);
        if (r < 128) {
            t += String.fromCharCode(r)
        } else if (r > 127 && r < 2048) {
            t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 | 192);
            t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128)
        } else {
            t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 12 | 224);
            t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 & 63 | 128);
            t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128)
        }
    }
    return t
}, _utf8_decode: function (e) {
    var t = "";
    var n = 0;
    var r = c1 = c2 = 0;
    while (n < e.length) {
        r = e.charCodeAt(n);
        if (r < 128) {
            t += String.fromCharCode(r);
            n++
        } else if (r > 191 && r < 224) {
            c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1);
            t += String.fromCharCode((r & 31) << 6 | c2 & 63);
            n += 2
        } else {
            c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1);
            c3 = e.charCodeAt(n + 2);
            t += String.fromCharCode((r & 15) << 12 | (c2 & 63) << 6 | c3 & 63);
            n += 3
        }
    }
    return t
}
```

}

For example, you can decode base64 encoded string like this:

var decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedstring);

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of resources on this but this should help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding.

The short and sweet answer:

```
var str = atob('stringOfBase64');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: atob() and btoat() are not available in SuiteScript

Comment: I tested out both `atob()` and `btoa()` in a SuiteScript Client script and they both worked. What was your error because I didn't have a problem?

Comment: It's a scheduled script

Comment: Hi @VicDid did you got the exact method in scheduled script

Comment: I found a BSD-3 licensed atob and btoa implementation in JS (https://github.com/jsdom/abab), but unfortunately it doesn't quite work out of the box in SuiteScript.  It uses template literals for making string copies, which is not supported in SuiteScript, and it has a const array declared as [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined] in a loop which unfortunately screws up the padding at the end (instead of getting ='s, you just get copies of whatever was left in the previous chunk).  Change the template literals to (' ' + s).slice(1) and change the const to a var and it works.